# php cli batch script randomly halts

Tags: php, mongodb, batch-file, command-line-interface

I'm having troubles with a PHP script that imports csv files into MongoDB.

There's one script named import_feeds.php, that calls (in a loop) another one named import_csv_file.php via exec:

```
exec("php import_csv_file.php --id=$id --file=$file --timestamp=$timestamp > logs/import_csv_file.log 2>&1", $output, $return);
```

The csv files usually have 10.000 lines of product information and there are around 4-5 mn lines total.

Currently I'm testing to import the same files over and over again, but the script randomly halts after around 4 mn lines have been processed.

There is no PHP error, nothing logged in mongod.log, nor in /var/log/messages, the script is still running, but it's just doing nothing.

It looks like the process stops while it tries to connect to MongoDB.

We are running a root server with 24GB RAM, 8 cores, 2x 1,5TB HDD software Raid1, Centos 5.6, MongoDB 1.8.2, Mongo client 1.2.1, PHP 5.2.16 (utterramblings)

Comment: The actual source code to debug is missing.

Comment: Just to make sure: are $id and $file properly sanitized?

Comment: Some clarifications. Is it a "halt" or a "hang"? Does `mongod` die or just become unresponsive? Are you using 64-bit? What file system? What does the disk throughput look like? Anything else working really hard? CPU? RAM? Disk?

Comment: It "hangs" and doesn't continue. Mongod doesn't die, but I was able to see that the script hangs during it tries to establish a connection to mongod via $link = new Mongo($uri);

Comment: It's 64-bit, Ext3. RAM is completely filled with data (MongoDB just takes what it can get...) CPU load is not that high, this script is just running on a single core, so there are 7 cores left. Disk seems to be slow...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your efforts. I updated to the latest mongodb php driver (1.2.2) and the problem disappeared.